# Variadic functions-ascending order

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Write an ascending function (int n, char type, ...) that receives a number n of values ​​and returns 1 if they are in strictly ascending order, otherwise 0. The type character indicates the type of values ​​and can be 'd' - you, 'in' - double.
Here is my try,but i'm kinda stuck.

```
double asc(int n,char tip,...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va,tip);
    va_list var;
    va_start(va,tip);
    while(--n)
    {
        if(tip=='d')
        {
            int va1=va_arg(va,int);
            if( va>va1)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        } 
        else
            if(tip=='f')
            {
                double va2=va_arg(va,double);
                if(va>va2)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
            }
    }
    return 0;

}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    asc(3,'d',-1,7,9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hello!I don't really understand what I'm suppose to do when I have more than 1 fixed variable.I mean when I have to accesses the next variadic function argument and to compare them to see if they are in ascending order,].

Comment: Why variadic instead of array?

Comment: Hints: a) comparing with the previous value will tell you if it has been ascending as compared to the previous value b) once it is not ascending with previous value you do not have to keep iterating c) if you looked through all the variables and found none which break ascending order, you know that it is in ascending order.

Comment: @stark because it is clearly a homework

Comment: So,basically I just need to use a break I guess.I have to use variadic function because this is the topic I'm trying to understand now. Also,I have some errors which I haven't been capable to adjust.                         
comparison between pointer and integer-if( va>va1)
invalid operands to binary > (have ‘__va_list_tag *’ and ‘double’)-  if(va>va2)

Comment: I'm just trying to learn more for myself and I've tried to do some exercises I have found on the internet.

Comment: @Alexx2901 Why does code call `va_start(va,tip);` twice?

Comment: @Alexx2901 "what I'm suppose to do when I have more than 1 fixed variable" --> use `va_start()` on the last fixed paramter.

Answer (score 0):

```
int asc(int n,char tip,...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va,tip);  
    int result = 1;
    union 
    {
        int i;
        double d;
    }val1, val2;
    if (n >= 2)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            switch(tip)
            {
                case 'i':
                    if(!i) {val1.i = va_arg(va, int);}
                    val2.i = va_arg(va, int);
                    if( val1.i > val2.i)
                        {result = 0; goto function_return;}
                    val1.i = val2.i;
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    if(!i) {val1.d = va_arg(va, double);}
                    val2.d = va_arg(va, double);
                    if( val1.d > val2.d)
                        {result = 0; goto function_return;}
                    val1.d = val2.d;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    function_return:
    va_end(va);
    return result;

}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", asc(4,'d',-1.0,7.0,9.0,0.0));
    return 0;
}
```